# how to create a video upload form in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form

i've created a video upload form and it seems that i get a limit error. Is this not hte way to create the form element?

```
$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
$file->setLabel('File')
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->setDestination('/var/www/tmp')
          ->addValidator('Size',
            false,
            array('min' => '10kB', 'max' => '100MB'));
$file->addValidator('Extension', false, 'avi,mov,wmv,mpeg,mp4,flv,mpg');
```

the error i get when uploading a 3MB file is: `File 'file' exceeds the defined ini size`.

any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Your php.ini file is most likely set to 2MB and unless you have permissions to change this, you won't be able to do anything about it.

Comment: What you say choose ... Do you mean browse for files to upload? If so, I don't think you have any control over that but you can decide which file types you will accept via upload.

Comment: for the file extension i added this: `$file->addValidator('Extension', false, 'avi,mov,wmv,mpeg,mp4,flv,mpg');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is down to a setting in *php.ini* `upload_max_filesize` not your validator

You also want to make sure `post_max_size` is appropriate

Also note `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are of type **PHP_INI_PERDIR**, which means *"Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf"*. So you can't set it in your script.

- `.htaccess` will only work if allow by webserver